# CS0117 - 'Method' does not contain a definition for 'POST'

Tags: restsharp

I have the following code and I'm not sure how to fix  it

```
client = new RestClient("https://xml.channelonline.com/REQUEST");
request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");
request.AddParameter("application/xml", xml, ParameterType.RequestBody);
request.AddHeader("X-Requested-With", "RestSharp");
request.AddHeader("Accept", "text/xml");
restResponse = client.Execute(request);
string response = restResponse.Content;
return response;
```

I'm getting the following error:

CS0117 - 'Method' does not contain a definition for 'POST'

I tried running the code but it didn't work